# Check white grease on the surface of white part by image processing

Tags: image-processing

Now I am doing a project about image processing. I want to check if there is any white grease on the
surface of a white part.
My method is to capture the image of part containing white grease and then process the image
to check if there is any white grease.
The problem is that the color of part and grease are almost the same (about 99%).
Therefore, I can't separate them and can't detect the grease.
Could you suggest me some ways/methods to check the white grease on the white part?
Maybe something like what kind of light, how to set up light, etc...
Thanks!

Comment: post an example image! As with image processing in general: trust your eyes. What do *you* have to do to get a clear impression of whether there's grease on the part? What are the parameters of imaging you can adjust (ie. can you use light of specific color)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the image right now but I will post it later. With my eyes, I can see the grease. It is shining. However, the camera can't. They are almost same with background color. I use camera Kiss x7 from Canon. I can change ISO,... I also use R, G, B light color but they don't help much.